Ciphertext collision in DES
I wanted to ask a question about DES cipher specifically, but it can really be extended to any symmetric-key encryption.
Let's say I have a ciphertext $c$, when $c = \mathrm{DES}(m,k_1)$.
Now, let's assume that I have some key, we'll call it $k_2$.
If the following equality holds:
$$\mathrm{DES}(m,k_1) = \mathrm{DES}(m,k_2)$$
Does that necessarily lead to the fact that $k_1 = k_2$?
In other words, is it possible for 2 different keys to produce the same ciphertext of a given plaintext?
Thanks.

Two different keys are possible; this was first demonstrated in 1989 by Quisquater and Delescaille.
They give the example
m=0404040404040404
k1=4A5AA8D0BA30585A
k2=46B2C8B62818F884
c=F02D67223CEAF91C
We expect similar results for other block ciphers. For a block cipher of width $B$-bits, by picking an arbitrary single block of plaintext and trying $O(2^{B/2})$ different keys, we expect a collision under the birthday paradox.

Thank you Daniel!
